# Why does info return questions_per_minute?

Tags: discussion, api

I started reading the API specification and realized that `info` returns `questions_per_minute`. Additionally with only two fractional digits, which means that even the 5th largest page in this network only returns `0.07` for this value. Is this really how this value should work? It's gonna be `0.00` for the vast majority of pages...

Comment: They once envisioned they would become a very, very big and popular site ...